# I am passing a prop from App.js to MovieCard.js but props passed is showing empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Complete github link -:  **https://github.com/dhruv354/movie-app.git**

### My App.js

**In App.js i am using Map function to iterate over data file which is a array of objects and passing
each object as a prop to Moviecard but it is showing empty**

```
import './App.css'
import React from 'react'
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import MovieCard from './MovieCard'
import data from './data'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Navbar />
     <div className='main'>
      <div className='tabs'>
        <div className='tab'>Movies</div>
        <div className ='tab'>Favourites</div>
      </div>

      <div className='movie-list'>
        {data.map((movie) => {
          <MovieCard movie = {movie} />
          return ''
        })}
      </div>
     </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### My MovieCard.js

**In Moviecard i am receving movie object as a prop , i tried console logging but it is showing empty**

```
import React from 'react';
    import './MovieCard.css';
    
    function MovieCard(props){
            console.log(props)
            const movie = props.movie
            return (
                // <div className='movie-card-container'>
                    <div className='movie-card'>
                        <div className='left'>
                            <img alt='movie-poster' src= {movie.Poster} />
                        </div>
                        <div className='right'>
                            <div className='title'>{movie.Title}</div>
                            <div className='plot'>{movie.Plot}</div>
                            <div className='footer'>
                                <div className='rating'>{movie.Imdb}</div>
                                <button className='favourite-btn'>Favourite</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                // </div>
            );
    }
    
    export default MovieCard;
```

### my Data.js

**this is a array of objects which is having information about a Movie like Plot, title, imdb and its Poster**

```
const data = [
    {
        Plot: 'It is 1941 and the world is in the throes of war. Steve Rogers (Chris Evans) wants to do his part and join Americas armed forces, but the military rejects him because of his small stature',
        Poster: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/ae/90/e7/ae90e774ef756936e18dfb287b28dd64.jpg',
        Imdb: 6.9,
        Title: 'Captain America'
    },

    {
        Plot: 'A thief who steals corporate secrets through the use of dream-sharing technology is given the inverse task of planting an idea into the mind of a C.E.O.',
        Poster: 'https://flxt.tmsimg.com/assets/p7825626_p_v10_af.jpg',
        Imdb: 8.8,
        Title: 'Inception'
    }
]

export default data;
```

**Please help**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well inside your `map` function you are returning an empty string each time:

```
{data.map((movie) => {
  <MovieCard movie = {movie} />
  return ''
})}
```

U should return the `JSX` instead:

```
{data.map((movie) => <MovieCard movie = {movie} /> )}
```

Comment: yes, it worked but what is wrong with my code

Comment: @dhruvsinghal that instead of returning the component u are returning an empty string. if this was helpful, consider upvoting and selecting it as the correct answer.

Comment: @dhruvsinghal an arrow function will return the value automatically if there are no brackets `{` `}`.  But if you have brackets then you need to include a `return` statement.  You have brackets so you either need to return the element `{data.map((movie) => { return <MovieCard movie={movie} /> })}` or just ditch the brackets so that it gets returned automatically `{data.map((movie) => <MovieCard movie={movie} />)}` [Read more about arrow functions here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)